# Calling another AsyncTask from onPostExecute method

Tags: android, android-asynctask, networkonmainthread

I want to call a new `AsyncTask` from `onPostExecute` of the currently finished `AsyncTask`.

```
          protected void onPostExecute(Integer feed) {
        dialog1.dismiss();          
        super.onPostExecute(feed);
        new SendsequenceofRequest().execute();
    }
```

But I'm receiving following exception:

```
        android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

My logcat output is:

```
09-30 16:08:19.517: W/System.err(3706): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
09-30 16:08:19.517: W/System.err(3706):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1077)
09-30 16:08:19.517: W/System.err(3706):     at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedNetworkSystem.read(BlockGuard.java:279)
09-30 16:08:19.517: W/System.err(3706):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:448)
09-30 16:08:19.517: W/System.err(3706):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:75)
09-30 16:08:19.517: W/System.err(3706):     at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:103)
09-30 16:08:19.517: W/System.err(3706):     at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.isStale(SocketInputBuffer.java:132)
09-30 16:08:19.517: W/System.err(3706):     at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.isStale(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:205)
09-30 16:08:19.517: W/System.err(3706):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.isStale(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:185)
09-30 16:08:19.577: W/System.err(3706):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:336)
09-30 16:08:19.577: W/System.err(3706):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
09-30 16:08:19.577: W/System.err(3706):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
09-30 16:08:19.597: W/System.err(3706):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
09-30 16:08:19.597: W/System.err(3706):     at com.dm.ekot.reqres.SimpleHttpClient.sendresponseSequReqRes(SimpleHttpClient.java:715)
09-30 16:08:19.607: W/System.err(3706):     at com.dm.ekot.MainScreen$SendsequenceofRequest$1$1.run(MainScreen.java:1020)
09-30 16:08:19.620: W/System.err(3706):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-30 16:08:19.620: W/System.err(3706):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-30 16:08:19.620: W/System.err(3706):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
09-30 16:08:19.620: W/System.err(3706):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
09-30 16:08:19.627: W/System.err(3706):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-30 16:08:19.627: W/System.err(3706):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
09-30 16:08:19.627: W/System.err(3706):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
09-30 16:08:19.627: W/System.err(3706):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
09-30 16:08:19.642: W/System.err(3706):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

In my `SendsequenceofRequest` `AsyncTask` I do start another thread in `doInBackground()` method.

```
            class SendsequenceofRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {

//  private ProgressDialog dialog1;

    protected void onPreExecute() {
    //  dialog1 = ProgressDialog.show(MainScreen.this, "", "Loading...");   
    }   

    protected void onPostExecute(Integer feed) {
    //  dialog1.dismiss();          
        super.onPostExecute(feed);
    }        

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... arg0) {    

                   String  str_stater_menu = "Starters";
                   String response_starter = "";
                try {

                    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            while (isThreadPaused1) {
                                try {
                                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {    

                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub   
                                            try {
                                                final String response_req_sequence = SimpleHttpClient.sendresponseSequReqRes(response_send_order);
                                                System.out.println(" i  ma in thread");
                                                if(response_req_sequence != null)
    {
                                                     onPause();
         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {    
                @Override  
                public void run() {    
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Order will be delivered in"+response_req_sequence, 10000).show();
                }
            });
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
                                        }
                                    });
                                } catch (Exception e) {  
                                    // TODO: handle exception
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }).start();
                    //response_starter = SimpleHttpClient.sendFirstStarter(str_stater_menu);
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }    
                   System.out.println("i am getting response for starter"+response_starter);
                // str_reponse_request_tableid_ip = SimpleHttpClient.sendIpTabletId(url , str_ip);

               /** 
                *      
                */
                //  res = response_starter.toString();
                  System.out.println("response TEST: "+res);
            //   Object obj = response_starter.toString();
               System.out.println("after object creation ");

              // getJsonStringForStarter(response_starter);

               System.out.println("response :"+res);       

           /** Inside the new thread we cannot update the main thread
           So updating the main thread outside the new thread */
           try {   

           }catch (Exception e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
              // e.printStackTrace();
           }
        return null;
           }       


    }
```

When i go through several link i couldn't found any help as my issue. So please nay body help me to take me out of this issue. Thanks in advance to all.

Comment: Why are you creating Threads in an AsyncTask? The whole point of them is so you don't have to manage your threads as much.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have to send request continuously to server until i didn't get any response. And this request will be executed after first request will complete. That why i am using it in onPostExecute method. If you have another solution or suggestion please help me..

Comment: You can do that in `doInBackground`. Just add a `while(true)` loop with `Thread.sleep(1000)` and once it's successful do a `break`

Comment: Your suggestion is really appreciated , but request is sending only once a time . I am using this - while (isThreadPaused1) {
                     try {
                         Thread.sleep(3000);

Comment: It's same, just without dozen of handle sand threads or runnables and instead of creating `AsyncTask` over and over again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest the use of `publishProgress` to publish the current progress and override `onProgressUpdate` which is executed on the main thread. With that, you won't have to use handlers and Threads in the `AsyncTask`  at all.

Notice that the first line has changed from `extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer>` to `extends AsyncTask<String, String, Integer>`. The middle parameter determines the object type of the Update Parameter. If you need to send complex data to the update method, change it to a class containing all information necessary.

```
class SendsequenceofRequest extends AsyncTask<String, String, Integer> {
    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... arg0) {    
        try {
            // This will run indefinitely, unless stopped by break. So make sure you have an exit condition, see below
            String response_req_sequence = null;
            do {
                response_req_sequence = SimpleHttpClient.sendresponseSequReqRes(response_send_order);
                if(response_req_sequence != null) {
                    // Instead of calling runOnUiThread, call progress update
                    publishProgress(response_req_sequence);
                }

                // Wait before retry
                Thread.sleep(3000);

            // Keep in mind, that if the connection is successful, the string may be empty,
            // so TextUtils.isEmpty(response_req_sequence); may be better exit condition as it checks if string is null or has size of 0
            } while(response_req_sequence!=null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    void onProgressUpdate(String... string) {
        // This will always be executed in main thread
        onPause();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Order will be delivered in"+response_req_sequence, 10000).show();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Integer feed) {
        // Notify user the task has bene completed
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Task completed.", 10000).show();
    }        
}
```

Comment: I got your suggestion but how i will send request again-and-again until i didn't get response.

Comment: That's done in the `doInBackground`. The `while(true)` will be called over and over again, until you call `break` inside it. I don't know your actual exit condition, that's why I used `if(somecondition == true)` as place holder. If `null` would be your exit condition then you can do `if(response_req_sequence==null) break;` to exit the while loop

Comment: Alternatively, you can also use do/while. I'll update my post with do/while and `response_req_sequence==null` as exit condition

Comment: you override onProgressUpdate method but why you are calling  publishProgress(response_req_sequence) method.?

Comment: Read the documentation please. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate%28Progress...%29

It says: "Runs on the UI thread after publishProgress(Progress...) is invoked. The specified values are the values passed to publishProgress(Progress...)."

`publishProgress` does the necessary work to invoke `onProgressUpdate` on the main thread.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38352/discussion-between-blue-green-and-tseng)

Comment: The method publishProgress(Void...) in the type AsyncTask<String,Void,Integer> is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Answer (score 0):

If `mHandler` was created from the main/UI thread, then any `Runnable`s posted to it will also run on the main thread. Since you're trying to perform network I/O inside such a `Runnable`, the app is throwing a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Comment: Thanks for quick response.. So what i should to to resolve my issue.

Comment: I suggest removing the `Handler` and `Thread` code from your `doInBackground()` method since, by definition, you're already running on a background thread. Please see Tseng's answer for a fuller solution.

Answer (score 0):

Runnable started by

```
mHandler.post(Runnable runnable);
```

is executed on main thread, and you are trying to use networking inside that runnable.

To avoid this problem simply create new thread and start it like this:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable {
...
});
t.start();
```

Comment: i already tried this but , this is showwing same exception for me.

Comment: There is no need to work with Threads, if you are going to use `AsyncTask`. The `AsyncTask` was made as convenience to make work easier to do and not work with handlers and threads directly. See my answer below

Comment: Did you try to use networking inside `doInBackground`? Why creating inside thread? You can use `Thread.sleep(...)` wrapped by `while` inside `doInBackground`.